# Android: When drawing circles on SurfaceView all other circles change positions

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to draw circles on touch on a **SurfaceView**.
Each time a new circle is added other ones seem to swap **X** and **Y** coordinates.
Here is **MyCanvas** class extends **SurfaceView**

```
public class MyCanvas extends SurfaceView{

private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public MyCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

                paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**And linked with Activity**

```
    surface = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    myCanvas = new MyCanvas(this);
    myCanvas.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    myCanvas.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    surface.addView(myCanvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not clearing the Canvas every frame, which is required by [`lockCanvas()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas()).  You're seeing things "move" because the surface is double- or triple-buffered, so you're seeing the previous contents of alternate buffers.

There's no mechanism that would cause drawn pixels to swap X/Y coordinates.  Make a series of touches in a horizontal line, left to right, and you should see alternating circles light up on each touch.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but is there a way to have multiple circles?

Comment: A couple of common approaches: (1) keep track of every touch, and draw every circle rather than just the newest one; (2) create a screen-sized Bitmap, render your circles onto that, and then just blit the entire Bitmap to the Surface's Canvas whenever a new one is added.